# Speed up data.frame rearrangement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with coordinates ("start","end") and labels ("group"):

```
a <- data.frame(start=1:4, end=3:6, group=c("A","B","C","D"))
a
  start end group
1     1   3     A
2     2   4     B
3     3   5     C
4     4   6     D
```

I want to create a new data frame in which labels are assigned to every element of the sequence on the range of coordinates:

```
   V1 V2
1   1  A
2   2  A
3   3  A
4   2  B
5   3  B
6   4  B
7   3  C
8   4  C
9   5  C
10  4  D
11  5  D
12  6  D
```

The following code works but it is extremely slow with wide ranges:

```
df<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){
    s<-seq(a[i,1],a[i,2])
    df<-rbind(df,data.frame(s,rep(a[i,3],length(s))))
}
colnames(df)<-c("V1","V2")
```

How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 4):

You can try *data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, start:end, by = group]
```

which gives

```
    group V1
 1:     A  1
 2:     A  2
 3:     A  3
 4:     B  2
 5:     B  3
 6:     B  4
 7:     C  3
 8:     C  4
 9:     C  5
10:     D  4
11:     D  5
12:     D  6
```

Obviously this would only work if you have one row per group, which it seems you have here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a very fast solution in base R, you can manually create the `data.frame` in two steps:

1. Use `mapply` to create a `list` of your ranges from "start" to "end".
2. Use `rep` + `lengths` to repeat the "groups" column to the expected number of rows.

The base R approach shared here won't depend on having only one row per group.

Try:

```
temp <- mapply(":", a[["start"]], a[["end"]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
data.frame(group = rep(a[["group"]], lengths(temp)),
           values = unlist(temp, use.names = FALSE))
```

If you're doing this a lot, just put it in a function:

```
myFun <- function(indf) {
  temp <- mapply(":", indf[["start"]], indf[["end"]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  data.frame(group = rep(indf[["group"]], lengths(temp)),
             values = unlist(temp, use.names = FALSE))
}
```

Then, if you want some sample data to try it with, you can use the following as sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- data.frame(start=1:4, end=sample(5:10, 4, TRUE), group=c("A","B","C","D"))
x <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1000, a, FALSE))
y <- do.call(rbind, replicate(100, x, FALSE))
```

Note that this does seem to slow down as the number of different unique values in "group" increases.

(In other words, the "data.table" approach will make the most sense in general. I'm just sharing a possible base R alternative that should be considerably faster than your existing approach.)